# Rails - username lowercase validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

My app validates username based on whether it's lowercase or uppercase. This is the validation I currently have: `format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/ }`, however, if I do this: `format: { with: /\A[a-z0-9]+\z/ }`, when user input uppercase letters it says that username is invalid even though username is not taken. How can I make username lowercase AND validate if it exists giving the ability to users input uppercase letters and not show `username is invalid`?

Comment: Not sure we can understand your question correctly because your validation works as expected. So you want to force making all username to be lowercase, or you want to validate if a username is all lowercase?

Comment: `Force making` means you allow user to use uppercase letter, but after that your application transform them all to lowercase and save to the database.

Comment: `validate if a username is all lowercase` means if user input a uppercase letter, the app should say `username is invalid` ( as your current situation )

Comment: @yeuem1vannam Sorry for confusing question. I was able to resolve the issue by adding ```:uniqueness => { case_sensitive: false }```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by adding `:uniqueness => { case_sensitive: false }` to username validation

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :username, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```